# How to find products that are in specific categories

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have **products** model like this

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  categories:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
             }
})
```

and **category** model

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true }
})
```

now

I wanna Filter Products by array of categories id

I send array of categories id `[_1234464 , _987654321]` in request body

**controller/products**

```
exports.get = async (req, res, next) => {
  categories=req.body.categories  // is like [_1234464 , _987654321] ;
 const filteredProducts= productModel.find({  /* i dont know what to write here*/  })
})
```

Comment: Use $in operator. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exports.get = async (req, res, next) => {
  categories=req.body.categories  // is like [_1234464 , 987654321] ;
 const filteredProducts= productModel.find({ categories:{$in:categories}  })
})
```

Comment: it worked , but the only problem i that if I send categories null or not to send it , it return nothing !
I wanna if i didn't send parameter It return all products

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer where it filters for categories only if they are set:

```
exports.get = async (req, res, next) => {
  categories=req.body.categories  // is like [_1234464 , 987654321] ;
 const filteredProducts= productModel.find(categories? { categories:{$in:categories}: {}  })
})
```